# How to restructure a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following json object which I want to restructure  -

```
"Consumption": [
  {
    
    "Daily_Consumption_Value": 65,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Fuel_Consumption_Id": 1484,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Id": 10199,
    "Fuel_Commodity_Id": 5,
    "Last_Modify_Date": "Nov 6, 2020",
    "Movement_Type_Enum": "Laden",
    "Fuel_Commodity_Code": "Fuel Oil"
  },
  {
    "Daily_Consumption_Value": 55,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Fuel_Consumption_Id": 1485,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Id": 10199,
    "Fuel_Commodity_Id": 5,
    "Last_Modify_Date": "Nov 6, 2020",
    "Movement_Type_Enum": "Ballast",
    "Fuel_Commodity_Code": "Fuel Oil"
  },
  {
    "Daily_Consumption_Value": 25,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Fuel_Consumption_Id": 1486,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Id": 10199,
    "Fuel_Commodity_Id": 5,
    "Last_Modify_Date": "Nov 6, 2020",
    "Movement_Type_Enum": "Idle",
    "Fuel_Commodity_Code": "Fuel Oil"
  },
  {
    "Daily_Consumption_Value": 55,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Fuel_Consumption_Id": 1487,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Id": 10199,
    "Fuel_Commodity_Id": 5,
    "Last_Modify_Date": "Nov 6, 2020",
    "Movement_Type_Enum": "Loading",
    "Fuel_Commodity_Code": "Fuel Oil"
  },
  {
    "Daily_Consumption_Value": 55,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Fuel_Consumption_Id": 1488,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Id": 10199,
    "Fuel_Commodity_Id": 5,
    "Last_Modify_Date": "Nov 6, 2020",
    "Movement_Type_Enum": "Discharging",
    "Fuel_Commodity_Code": "Fuel Oil"
  },
  {
    "Daily_Consumption_Value": 0.02,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Fuel_Consumption_Id": 1489,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Id": 10199,
    "Fuel_Commodity_Id": 58,
    "Last_Modify_Date": "Nov 6, 2020",
    "Movement_Type_Enum": "Laden",
    "Fuel_Commodity_Code": "MDO"
  },
  {
    "Daily_Consumption_Value": 0.01,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Fuel_Consumption_Id": 1490,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Id": 10199,
    "Fuel_Commodity_Id": 58,
    "Last_Modify_Date": "Nov 6, 2020",
    "Movement_Type_Enum": "Ballast",
    "Fuel_Commodity_Code": "MDO"
  },
  {
    "Daily_Consumption_Value": 0.02,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Fuel_Consumption_Id": 1491,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Id": 10199,
    "Fuel_Commodity_Id": 58,
    "Last_Modify_Date": "Nov 6, 2020",
    "Movement_Type_Enum": "Idle",
    "Fuel_Commodity_Code": "MDO"
  },
  {
    "Daily_Consumption_Value": 0.02,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Fuel_Consumption_Id": 1492,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Id": 10199,
    "Fuel_Commodity_Id": 58,
    "Last_Modify_Date": "Nov 6, 2020",
    "Movement_Type_Enum": "Loading",
    "Fuel_Commodity_Code": "MDO"
  },
  {
    "Daily_Consumption_Value": 0.02,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Fuel_Consumption_Id": 1493,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Id": 10199,
    "Fuel_Commodity_Id": 58,
    "Last_Modify_Date": "Nov 6, 2020",
    "Movement_Type_Enum": "Discharging",
    "Fuel_Commodity_Code": "MDO"
  }
]
```

I want to restructure the Json object like this -

```
consumption = [
    {
      Fuel: "Fuel Oil",
      Laden: 65,
      Ballast: 55,
      Idle: 25,
      Loading: 55,
      Discharging: 55,
    },
    {
      Fuel: "MDO",
      Laden: 0.02,
      Ballast: 0.01,
      Idle: 0.02,
      Loading: 0.02,
      Discharging: 0.02,
    },
  ]
```

I have tried the following code -

```
var tmp = {};

    res.forEach(function (item) {
      var tempKey = item.Fuel_Commodity_Code;

      if (!tmp.hasOwnProperty(tempKey)) {
        tmp[tempKey] = {
          Fuel: item.Fuel_Commodity_Code,
          Laden: "",
          Ballast: "",
          Idle: "",
          Loading: "",
          Discharging: "",
        };
      }

      tmp[tempKey].Laden = item.Daily_Consumption_Value;
      tmp[tempKey].Ballast = item.Daily_Consumption_Value;
      tmp[tempKey].Idle = item.Daily_Consumption_Value;
      tmp[tempKey].Loading = item.Daily_Consumption_Value;
      tmp[tempKey].Discharging = item.Daily_Consumption_Value;
    });

    var results = Object.keys(tmp).map(function (key) {
      return tmp[key];
    });
    console.log(results);
  }
```

But I do not get the desired output. I get something like this which has the same value for all the keys except the Fuel  -

```
0:
Ballast: 55
Discharging: 55
Fuel: "Fuel Oil"
Idle: 55
Laden: 55
Loading: 55

1:
Ballast: 0.02
Discharging: 0.02
Fuel: "MDO"
Idle: 0.02
Laden: 0.02
Loading: 0.02
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Could you please guide me how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit awkward to express your output as an array, it might be better to make it an object where the key is the Fuel_Commodity_Code. That would save using the find method, instead you look up the desired record by the key. But this code abides by your desired format, I think:

```js
consumption = [
  {
    
    "Daily_Consumption_Value": 65,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Fuel_Consumption_Id": 1484,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Id": 10199,
    "Fuel_Commodity_Id": 5,
    "Last_Modify_Date": "Nov 6, 2020",
    "Movement_Type_Enum": "Laden",
    "Fuel_Commodity_Code": "Fuel Oil"
  },
  {
    "Daily_Consumption_Value": 55,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Fuel_Consumption_Id": 1485,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Id": 10199,
    "Fuel_Commodity_Id": 5,
    "Last_Modify_Date": "Nov 6, 2020",
    "Movement_Type_Enum": "Ballast",
    "Fuel_Commodity_Code": "Fuel Oil"
  },
  {
    "Daily_Consumption_Value": 25,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Fuel_Consumption_Id": 1486,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Id": 10199,
    "Fuel_Commodity_Id": 5,
    "Last_Modify_Date": "Nov 6, 2020",
    "Movement_Type_Enum": "Idle",
    "Fuel_Commodity_Code": "Fuel Oil"
  },
  {
    "Daily_Consumption_Value": 55,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Fuel_Consumption_Id": 1487,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Id": 10199,
    "Fuel_Commodity_Id": 5,
    "Last_Modify_Date": "Nov 6, 2020",
    "Movement_Type_Enum": "Loading",
    "Fuel_Commodity_Code": "Fuel Oil"
  },
  {
    "Daily_Consumption_Value": 55,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Fuel_Consumption_Id": 1488,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Id": 10199,
    "Fuel_Commodity_Id": 5,
    "Last_Modify_Date": "Nov 6, 2020",
    "Movement_Type_Enum": "Discharging",
    "Fuel_Commodity_Code": "Fuel Oil"
  },
  {
    "Daily_Consumption_Value": 0.02,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Fuel_Consumption_Id": 1489,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Id": 10199,
    "Fuel_Commodity_Id": 58,
    "Last_Modify_Date": "Nov 6, 2020",
    "Movement_Type_Enum": "Laden",
    "Fuel_Commodity_Code": "MDO"
  },
  {
    "Daily_Consumption_Value": 0.01,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Fuel_Consumption_Id": 1490,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Id": 10199,
    "Fuel_Commodity_Id": 58,
    "Last_Modify_Date": "Nov 6, 2020",
    "Movement_Type_Enum": "Ballast",
    "Fuel_Commodity_Code": "MDO"
  },
  {
    "Daily_Consumption_Value": 0.02,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Fuel_Consumption_Id": 1491,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Id": 10199,
    "Fuel_Commodity_Id": 58,
    "Last_Modify_Date": "Nov 6, 2020",
    "Movement_Type_Enum": "Idle",
    "Fuel_Commodity_Code": "MDO"
  },
  {
    "Daily_Consumption_Value": 0.02,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Fuel_Consumption_Id": 1492,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Id": 10199,
    "Fuel_Commodity_Id": 58,
    "Last_Modify_Date": "Nov 6, 2020",
    "Movement_Type_Enum": "Loading",
    "Fuel_Commodity_Code": "MDO"
  },
  {
    "Daily_Consumption_Value": 0.02,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Fuel_Consumption_Id": 1493,
    "Deal_Master_Voyage_Calc_Id": 10199,
    "Fuel_Commodity_Id": 58,
    "Last_Modify_Date": "Nov 6, 2020",
    "Movement_Type_Enum": "Discharging",
    "Fuel_Commodity_Code": "MDO"
  }
]

result = consumption.reduce((accum, obj) => {
    if (!(accum.find(record => record.Fuel === obj.Fuel_Commodity_Code))) {
       accum.push({
         Fuel: obj.Fuel_Commodity_Code
       })
    }
    
    const record = (accum.find(record => record.Fuel === obj.Fuel_Commodity_Code))
    
    record[obj.Movement_Type_Enum] = obj.Daily_Consumption_Value
    return accum
   }, [])
   
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tmp = {};

    res.forEach(function (item) {
      var tempKey = item.Fuel_Commodity_Code;

      if (!tmp.hasOwnProperty(tempKey)) {
        tmp[tempKey] = {
          Fuel: "",
          Laden: "",
          Ballast: "",
          Idle: "",
          Loading: "",
          Discharging: "",
        };
      }
      tmp[tempKey].Fuel = item.Fuel_Commodity_Code;
      tmp[tempKey].Laden = item.Daily_Consumption_Value;
      tmp[tempKey].Ballast = item.Daily_Consumption_Value;
      tmp[tempKey].Idle = item.Daily_Consumption_Value;
      tmp[tempKey].Loading = item.Daily_Consumption_Value;
      tmp[tempKey].Discharging = item.Daily_Consumption_Value;
    });

    var results = Object.keys(tmp).map(function (key) {
      return tmp[key];
    });
    console.log(results);
  }
```